# Getting a list of all TFS checked out files

Tags: azure-devops

I am aware that in the past, this was possible via TFS Power Tools, but that seems to have been deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **tf** command, if you installed visual studio 2017 or 2019.

Open **Developer Command Prompt for VS**, and run below command.

```
Tf.exe status /collection:"<project collection URL>" /user:* /recursive
```

tf.exe is now integerated with VS2017/VS2019. You can find it in Visual Studio installation folder (eg. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`)